# How can we play split screen in the XBOX 360 version of Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

My little brother and I want to play Minecraft together on the Xbox 360, and we heard there was a split screen option. We've looked inside the options menu but weren't able to find it. Does the game really have a split screen option, and if so, how do we enable it?

Comment: Isn't is automatic?

Comment: You can, but you also need to be using 720p video. Perhaps that's the issue?

Answer (score 6):

The XBOX 360 version of Minecraft does have a split screen option, and the instructions for doing can be found on the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Splitscreen).

The split screen mode does require a monitor with 720p output, and you'll need to configure the 360 accordingly:

> Because Splitscreen requires a screen with an output of 720p or higher, the Xbox 360's video output needs to be configured accordingly. The video mode can be checked by going to **Settings > System > Console Settings > Display** - Make sure this is set to 720p or higher.

If the XBOX 360 is configured then all you need to do know is have the the player who wishes to join press "Start" on the controller she wishes to use after you've loaded a world (make sure it's not an online game). This will prompt the user to log-in. After the play logs in split screen should be enabled automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The video below shows what you want to know.

but for better clarity here is some contextual information:

**Requirements:**

- HDMI OR VGA OR HD AV OR RGB component cable
- Need a HD TV cannot have a SD (standard definition) TV
- Obviously need two controllers

**What should be done:**

1. connect the Xbox to the TV via any of the cable options above
2. Make sure both controllers are turned on and they have a user account on them
3. Play Minecraft

[Source - Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Splitscreen)

Comment: hmm i thought this was a good answer

Comment: We try to provide the information needed for an answer in the answer itself here, in case whatever source is linked gets taken down. I'm not sure if that's why you got downvoted, but it's a decent guess. If you were to take the info from the video and type it out you'd have a perfectly decent answer as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: OH okay ill add some info

Comment: @Fambida That's likely why he got downvoted. [As this meta shows](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6864/does-arqade-frown-upon-youtube-videos-as-answers), the community tends to frown upon just posting a Youtube video as an answer. IF you included a summary of the information in the video I suspect the downvoting users would revmove their downvote (assuming, of course, they see your edits).

Comment: I just edited to sum up the most of the things he says

Comment: The poor English is another reason this is a bad answer

Comment: I think with this edit will be back to 0 (at least) in no time =) Try to add more format and context on the answers and questions. help other users that come in the site looking for the answers