# Can my twins play Minecraft together on Xbox 360 live with just one Xbox Live account?

Tags: xbox-360, minecraft-legacy-console

So far I have resisted getting Xbox Live for my twins. They were 7 in October but for Christmas they have been bought it by their uncle. I cannot, however, work out how they can both play together when their cousin invites them to play Minecraft. Is it possible for them both to play together on one console with one account or if not what is the cheapest solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can we play split screen in the XBOX 360 version of Minecraft?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/155988/how-can-we-play-split-screen-in-the-xbox-360-version-of-minecraft)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I dont think this is the solution they have been playing together in split screen mode for two years offline. The problem is now we have xbox live they cannot play together online when they have been invited into a game.

Comment: In which case it may be difficult. Splitscreen doesn't play well with online servers; they may have to create the server and invite the cousin. [Here's a link to the relevant wiki page](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Splitscreen), hopefully someone more knowledgable than me will post an answer.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use one account for two people. One account must have Xbox Live Gold and the other account must be signed into the Xbox Live 'Guest' Profile. Here's what you do:

1. Turn on the Xbox and both controllers
2. Make sure that you have a secure internet connection (wired or wireless)
3. Have Player 1 sign into the Xbox Live Gold profile
4. Start Minecraft
5. Have the Player 2 sign into the account **'Guest'**, do not make an account called Guest. (If you can't find the Guest profile, don't worry, just follow the next step)
6. When invited to the game, a four-pane sign-in window will pop-up and give the options **'Start'** or **'Join'**. If the second player has not signed in already, have them click 'Join' and sign into the Guest profile.

   [image: The Start/Join popup with two LIVE members and a Guest signed on]
7. Click **'Start'** and they will connect to the game
8. Enjoy!

This method will support up to 4 players on one Xbox. **Remember to have the guests store their inventory AND armor into a chest because it will not save Guest profile progress. Only the profile with Xbox Live Gold will keep their level AND equipment.**

I did this the other day with my friends and it worked great!

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to answer I will try this later and let you know if we were successful.

Comment: Not a problem! Hope this works for you!

Answer (score -1):

You can! But you must have a flat screen hooked up by HDMI. No old TV

Comment: What does HDMI have to do with it?